# directory recursion causes infinite loop

Tags: php, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to read a directory recursively and find the matching files in it:

```
function readFiles($sBaseDir)
{
    $pointer = opendir($sBaseDir);
    while (false !== ($sFilePath = readdir($pointer)))
    {
        if (is_dir($sFilePath))
        {
            closedir($pointer);
            readFiles($sFilePath);
        }

        else
        {
            $arPaths = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $sFilePath);
            $sFileName = $arPaths[count($arPaths) - 1];

            $sEnding = substr($sFileName, strpos($sFileName, '.'));
            if ($sEnding === '.rpm' || $sEnding === '.deb' || $sEnding === '.tar.gz' || $sEnding === '.tazpkg')
            {
                echo '<a href="index.php?getfile=' . urlencode($sFilePath) . '">' . $sFileName . '</a><br />' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}

readFiles(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'download');
```

But after the first iteration it´s next iteration is always `.`. So, the script always searches the same directory and could not be finished, yet. But I am wondering why, it should work, shouldn´t it?

Comment: Try this 

        if (is_dir($sFilePath) && $sFilePath!='.' && $sFilePath!='..')
        {
            closedir($pointer);
            readFiles($sFilePath);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readdir` doesn't return a full pathname, it just returns the name within the directory. You need to prepend the base directory to it. And there's no need to split the name, since it won't contain any directory separators. You should also check for `.` and `..` and skip them to prevent infinite recursion. Finally, you shouldn't call `closedir()` in the middle of the loop, as that will prevent further iterations; do that at the end of the `while` loop.

```
function readFiles($sBaseDir)
{
    $pointer = opendir($sBaseDir);
    while (false !== ($sFilePath = readdir($pointer)))
    {
        if ($sFilePath == '.' || $sFilePath == '..') {
            continue; // Skip . and .. to prevent infinite looping
        }
        $fullPath = $sBaseDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $sFilePath;
        if (is_dir($fullPath))
        {
            readFiles($fullPath);
        }

        else
        {
            $sEnding = substr($sFilePath, strpos($sFilePath, '.'));
            if ($sEnding === '.rpm' || $sEnding === '.deb' || $sEnding === '.tar.gz' || $sEnding === '.tazpkg')
            {
                echo '<a href="index.php?getfile=' . urlencode($fullPath) . '">' . $sFileName . '</a><br />' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($pointer);
}
```